# Are these files a complete site or

Tags: wordpress

A developer was paid to design a site and delivered files to the client then went bust and disappeared, is the attached file list a complete site or does it need an install of wordpressor something and some manipulation?

It came as a zip file and inside were two folders : `/_MACOSX` and `/r2rcomau`

In the folder `/r2rcomau` there were three folders and a bunch of files:

```
css
images
js
404.php
archive.php
author.php
category.php
comments.php
favicon.php
footer.php
functions.php
include-product.php
index.php
header.php
home-video.mp4
home-video.webm
page-nosidebar.php
page-team.php
screenshot.png
search.php
searchform.php
single-products.php
single.php
style.css
taxonomy-productcategories.php"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read [the Codex about Basic Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Basic_Templates), the above files pass the test for qualifying as a WordPress theme.

> At the very minimum, a WordPress Theme consists of two files:
>
> - style.css
> - index.php
>
> Both of these files go into the Theme directory.

In order to use this theme, you'll need to [install WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress), add those theme files, and activate the theme.

Without seeing the file contents, we won't be able to tell you whether or not the theme actually functions as a theme...but it passes the "qualifies as a WordPress theme" test.

Comment: thank you, I have installed wordpress on the server and it has a directory called Themes inside a directory called Wp-content there are four directories inside Themes: Flow (which was the template i had to choose when installing wordpress, Twntyfourteen Twentythirteen and Twnetytwelve and a file (index.php)... should I add those files to a directory off Themes named as my domain directory is?. I know this question reveals my absolute lack of knowledge in this area and if you think it shows ineptitude can you advise a developer that might do it for me for a price?

Comment: You should be able to add the entire `/r2rcomau` folder to your server (within the `/themes` directory). You'll then want to go to your WordPress Admin Dashboard and "activate" the r2rcomau theme.

Comment: thanks i did this and it is not functional. i get a blank screen.

Comment: Sounds like a possible broken theme.